# Setting up Infiniband network - wrong route

Tags: networking, configuration, static-ip, static-routes, infiniband

So I'm trying to set up an Infiniband network alongside my Ethernet network.

I have 10 compute nodes and one conductor node. All 11 machines are running CentOS and are plugged in to an Infiniband switch and an Ethernet switch.

Ethernet: 192.168.1.0/24
Infiniband: 192.168.2.0/24

The conductor node is 192.168.1.125 (Ethernet) and 192.168.2.125 (Infiniband). Compute node X is 192.168.1.10X (Ethernet) and 192.1.168.2.10X (Ethernet). All IP addresses are assigned statically.

So I log in to one of the compute nodes (compute-7):

Here is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-em1`

```
DEVICE=em1
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no

IPADDR=192.168.1.107
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.1.0
BROADCAST=192.168.1.255
GATEWAY=192.168.1.125   #via conductor node
DNS1=192.168.1.125   #via conductor node
```

Here is `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-ib0`

```
DEVICE=ib0
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
IPV6INIT=no
USERCTL=no
TYPE=InfiniBand

IPADDR=192.168.2.107
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NETWORK=192.168.2.0
BROADCAST=192.168.2.255
```

When I do:

`sudo network restart` on this compute node, here is `ifconfig -a`:

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:3A:FB  
          inet addr:192.168.1.107  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1236641045 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1239585124 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1561224959733 (1.4 TiB)  TX bytes:1560979085053 (1.4 TiB)
          Memory:91220000-91240000 

ib0       Link encap:InfiniBand  HWaddr 80:00:00:48:FE:80:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00  
          inet addr:192.168.2.107  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:2044  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:256 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

And `route -nn` gives:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ib0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 ib0
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.125   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
```

This is not what I want! I want 192.168.2.107 (compute node 7) to be able to talk to 192.168.2.108 (compute node 8) via the 192.168.2.x network. The above route is incorrect!

***My Infiniband nodes can't talk to each other in this case...***  - requests to the 192.168.2.0/24 subnet are routed via 192.168.1.125 (Ethernet) which is very slow...

I have been trying to set the files

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-em1`

and

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ib0`

With lines like:

`192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.1.125 dev em1`

`192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.125 dev ib0`

But every time I restart the network, I get the wrong routing...

Can anyone please help me as to how I might get the correct routing?

I'm afraid I don't have a complete network understanding and am finding I'm "hacking" a lot here...

Can anyone help me? All I want to do is to be able to do `ssh ostrich@compute-8-ib`(Infiniband) the way I currently can do `ssh ostrich@compute-8` (Ethernet)

Once I have a static network figured out, I'll do it all using DHCP and named, but for now; I'm just focussing on getting it right statically.

@Frederic Nielsen:

Here is the routing table on the conductor node:

```
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ib0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
137.43.92.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.254.0   U     0      0        0 em2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 em2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1004   0        0 ib0
0.0.0.0         187.42.92.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em2
```

Comment: The routing table seems correct as requests for the `192.168.2.0` network goes out through the `ib0` interface.. Maybe you should look somewhere else?

Comment: When I do `ssh 192.168.2.101` from the conductor node, I can't login? "ssh: connect to host 192.168.2.101 port 22: No route to host"

Comment: What does the routing table from the conductor node look like?

Comment: 192.168.2.107 and 192.168.2.108 are on the same network - you shouldn't need a route to talk. Are they arping properly?

Comment: @FrederikNielsen Thank you for your comment. I just updated the question with the conductor node's routing table.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like it should.. What does the arp table say?

Comment: @MaQleod Thank you for your comment. When I do `arp -a` I see nothing on 192.168.2.X. I can see all the 192.168.1.Xs though...

Comment: I should say that I can ibping between all GUIDs connected to the switch.

Comment: ipoib requires standard arp - you should see ipoib entries in the arp table that will have the GUID and IP of the ib devices on the same network.

Comment: @MaQleod I'm afraid I can't see anything to do with Infiniband with `arp -a` Do you have any suggestions?